# SQLite strftime query issue

Tags: sql, sqlite

HI i'm trying to execute this query in c but i always get  "no such function: strftime "

```
str = "SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',TIMESTAMP) AS 'Data',"
                "SUM (PEOPLENUMBER) AS 'PEOPLENUMBER'"
                "FROM COUNTINGEVENT WHERE TIMESTAMP >= '2017-01-19'"
                "AND TIMESTAMP < '2017-01-21'"
                "GROUP BY strftime('%d%H%M',TIMESTAMP)"
                "ORDER BY Data;";
```

this is the definition of Timestamp inside the table countingevent

```
"TIMESTAMP  DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
```

how i can resolve ??

Comment: You have single quotes around the column alias `DATA`.  Remove them.

Comment: The query looks OK to me, but have you tried running it in sqlite to confirm it works as expected?

Comment: removed the single quotes but i have the same problem. Yes the query on SQLiteManager(the firefox addon) and my db works well but on eclipse no

Comment: In which language/environment are you using the SQLite library?

Comment: c , using eclipse neon 2 on ubuntu 16.4

Answer (score 0):

Use 'now' instead of the 'TIMESTAMP'

Comment: with now i get the timestamp of today but i need the timestamp that are saved inside my table. however also with 'now' i get the same error. i'm programming in c using eclipse neon2 on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: if you want to get TIMESTAMP which is saved in local table then use column name in place of  of the 'now' like strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S','<column name>')

Comment: the column name is TIMESTAMP ! but the problem is that the query is not executed. i have always  "no such function: strftime" i tryed also with a different column name

Comment: try puting  'TIMESTAMP'  which is your column in single quote only for strftime